# how to get json object inner json array and jsonObject

Tags: android, arrays, json

hello in my programs i have Json like this

```
{"AgentTrxID":"201802090013",
    "Data":
[{      "Amount":"000006000.00",
        "Denda":"00000000",
        "kubikasi":"00103000-00000000",
        "Periode":"201710"}],
    "Header":
[{      "Total":6000,
        "AdminFee":2500,
        "IDPelanggan":"0416610037",
        "Biller":"PDAM TIRTANADI",
        "Alamat":"JAGUNG Gg COMP BGR",
        "GolonganTarif":"RT.3",
        "NomerReffTrans":"",
        "Nama":"NADHIRAH OKTARI"}],
        "AgentStoreID":"01010101",
        "message":"SUCCESS",
        "code":"00"
}
```

in inner json have 2 array how i can get object inner array and that object thank you

Comment: what do you mean `object inner array` and `that object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the json data as string with name text to the below code :

```
    JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(text);
    JSONArray dataArray = outerObject.getJSONArray("Data");
    JSONObject objectInsideData = dataArray.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONArray headerArray = outerObject.getJSONArray("Header");
    JSONObject objectInsideHeader = headerArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: i will try this is for android?

Comment: Yup android or any other language supporting json in java

Answer (score 0):

Depends what are you using like below I am using Gson to parse this JSON into some POJO.

if you choose to use the default Json Api available on android then you can do something like this.

```
 public void parseJson(JsonObject rootObj){
  if(rootObj.has("Data")){
     JSONArray array = rootObj.getJSONArray("Data");
     for(int count = 0; count<array.length(); count++){
       JSONObject inner = array.getJSONObject(count);
       //use inner object 
     }
  }
 }
```

The Gson way

```
public void parseJson(JsonObject rootObj){
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Example exp = gson.fromJson(rootObj,Example.class);
 //your json is parsed use pojo to access the array inside
}
```

Pojo goes like this

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("AgentTrxID")
@Expose
private String agentTrxID;
@SerializedName("Data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;
@SerializedName("Header")
@Expose
private List<Header> header = null;
@SerializedName("AgentStoreID")
@Expose
private String agentStoreID;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;

public String getAgentTrxID() {
return agentTrxID;
}

public void setAgentTrxID(String agentTrxID) {
this.agentTrxID = agentTrxID;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

public List<Header> getHeader() {
return header;
}

public void setHeader(List<Header> header) {
this.header = header;
}

public String getAgentStoreID() {
return agentStoreID;
}

public void setAgentStoreID(String agentStoreID) {
this.agentStoreID = agentStoreID;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

}
```

Header

```
public class Header {

@SerializedName("Total")
@Expose
private Integer total;
@SerializedName("AdminFee")
@Expose
private Integer adminFee;
@SerializedName("IDPelanggan")
@Expose
private String iDPelanggan;
@SerializedName("Biller")
@Expose
private String biller;
@SerializedName("Alamat")
@Expose
private String alamat;
@SerializedName("GolonganTarif")
@Expose
private String golonganTarif;
@SerializedName("NomerReffTrans")
@Expose
private String nomerReffTrans;
@SerializedName("Nama")
@Expose
private String nama;

public Integer getTotal() {
return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
this.total = total;
}

public Integer getAdminFee() {
return adminFee;
}

public void setAdminFee(Integer adminFee) {
this.adminFee = adminFee;
}

public String getIDPelanggan() {
return iDPelanggan;
}

public void setIDPelanggan(String iDPelanggan) {
this.iDPelanggan = iDPelanggan;
}

public String getBiller() {
return biller;
}

public void setBiller(String biller) {
this.biller = biller;
}

public String getAlamat() {
return alamat;
}

public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
this.alamat = alamat;
}

public String getGolonganTarif() {
return golonganTarif;
}

public void setGolonganTarif(String golonganTarif) {
this.golonganTarif = golonganTarif;
}

public String getNomerReffTrans() {
return nomerReffTrans;
}

public void setNomerReffTrans(String nomerReffTrans) {
this.nomerReffTrans = nomerReffTrans;
}

public String getNama() {
return nama;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
this.nama = nama;
}

}
```

Datum

```
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("Amount")
@Expose
private String amount;
@SerializedName("Denda")
@Expose
private String denda;
@SerializedName("kubikasi")
@Expose
private String kubikasi;
@SerializedName("Periode")
@Expose
private String periode;

public String getAmount() {
return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
this.amount = amount;
}

public String getDenda() {
return denda;
}

public void setDenda(String denda) {
this.denda = denda;
}

public String getKubikasi() {
return kubikasi;
}

public void setKubikasi(String kubikasi) {
this.kubikasi = kubikasi;
}

public String getPeriode() {
return periode;
}

public void setPeriode(String periode) {
this.periode = periode;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's PHP CODE:

First take this in string or in file.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($target_file),TRUE);
```

to access your First Array You can use following code in php.

```
foreach ($json['Data'] as $key => $value)
    {  echo $value['Amount'];
```

}

To access second array use following code:

```
foreach ($json['Header'] as $key => $value)
    {  echo $value['Total'];
```

}